# How to hide drop down Menu when user clicked out side of drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried below code , but it's not working

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#menu').click(function(){
        if($('#menu_list').css('display')=='none')
            $('#menu_list').show();
        else
        $('#menu_list').hide();
    });
    $('#menu_list').click(function(){
        $('#menu_list').hide();
    }
    );
});
</script>
<style>
#menu_list li:hover{
    background:#C9C;
}
#menu{
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
}
#menu_list{
    background:#C90;
    width:30px;
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:4;
}
#menulist li{
    padding:3px;
}
</style>
<body>
<input type="button" id="menu" value="drop" />
    <div id="menu_list">
            <li>a</li>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>a</li>
    </div>
</body>
```

i have tried using layer but when i am using layer then for another drop down i have to click `TWO time` to activate . so how to achieve this in 1 clock .
2nd Attempt When there exist `more than 1 drop down menu .`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var hide  = ['#list1','#list2'];
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('#a').click(function (){
        if($('#list1').css('display')=='none'){ 
            $('#list1').show();
            $('#close').show();
        }
        else {
        $('#close').hide();
        $('#list1').hide();
        }
    });

    $('#close').click(function(){
        for(i=0;i<hide.length;i++){
            $(hide[i]).hide();
        }
        $('#close').hide();
    });

     $('#b').click(function(){
        if($('#list2').css('display')=='none'){
            $('#list1').hide();
            $('#list2').show();
            $('#close').show();
        }
        else {
        $('#list2').hide();
        $('#close').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style>
#menu_list li:hover{
    background:#C9C;
}
#menu{
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
}
.menu_list{
    background:#C90;
    width:30px;
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:4;
    display:none;
}
#menulist li{
    padding:3px;
}
#close{
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:3;
    display:none;
}
.l{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="close">
</div>
<div class="l">
    <input type="button" class="menu" id="a" value="drop1" />
    <div class="menu_list" id="list1">
            <li>a</li>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>a</li>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="l">
    <input type="button" class="menu" value="drop2" id="b"/>
    <div class="menu_list" id="list2">
            <li>b</li>
            <li>b</li>
            <li>b</li>
            <li>b</li>
    </div>
</div>    
</body>
```

Comment: can you provide fiddle for that

Comment: http://jsbin.com/qesah/1/   fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to use that much of code for the purpose, use like this,

```
$(".menu").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".menu_list").hide();
    $(this).next().show();

});
$(document).click(function (e) {

    $(".menu_list").hide();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZN3aD/13/)

**Edit**

The `event.stopPropagation()` method stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being executed.

In the above code, I've written code for both `document` click and `.menu` click. Since `.menu` is in the document itself, when i click on `.menu`, there will generate the click event of `document` too. Which will hide `$(".menu_list")`. So I need to prevent that behaviour. Thats why i used `event.stopPropagation()`

**Update**

```
$(".menu").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".menu_list").not($(this).next()).hide();
    $(this).next().toggle();

});
$(".menu_list").find("li").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert($(this).text());
});
$(document).click(function (e) {

    $(".menu_list").hide();
});
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZN3aD/22/)

Comment: Hey can you elaborate what is e.stopPropagation() ? and What is the effect of this event and How this code works ?

Comment: How to hide when user click on a menu that is displayed .

Comment: @user3610792 can you explain more about your need?

Comment: Yeah , when user click on drop1 again then it should hide menulist , which is displayed at that time .

Comment: Thanku , When you start using JQuery in your project ?

Comment: Just want to know , how much time it will take for me to learn JQuery like that .

Comment: Note that this won't work if the dropdowns are created dynamically, while using event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the stopPropagation() method as shown:

```
$('#close').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: can you elaborate what is  stopPropagation() ? I have read about it , but not getting , where i have to use and how to use it ?

Comment: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event. http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the drop down as follows

```
$(document).click(function(){
 if ($(e.target).attr('id') != 'menu')
 $('#menu_list').hide();
});
```

Also, instead of checking the style attribute every time, i'd suggest using `toggleClass()` as follows

css

```
.hidden {
 display:none;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
 $('#menu').click(function () {
    $('#menu_list').toggleClass('hidden');
 });
 $('#menu_list').click(function () {
    $('#menu_list').addClass('hidden');;
 });
 $(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).attr('id') != 'menu') $('#menu_list').addClass('hidden');
 });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qQ22G/1/)

*Side note:*
the structure

```
<div id="menu_list">
   <li>a</li>
   <li>a</li>
   <li>a</li>
   <li>a</li>
</div>
```

is semantically incorrect.

it should be

```
<ul id="menu_list">
   <li>a</li>
   <li>a</li>
   <li>a</li>
   <li>a</li>
</ul>
```

**Update**

For making it work with multiple drop downs, you need to use `class`es instead of `id`'s and tweak some html and css properties.

HTML

```
<div class='dropdown'>
 <input type="button" class="menu" value="drop" />
 <ul class="menu_list hidden">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>a</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
 $('.menu').click(function () {
    $(this).next('.menu_list').toggleClass('hidden');
 });
 $('.menu_list').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('hidden');;
 });
 $(document).click(function (e) {
    if (!e.target.classList.contains('menu'))
      $('.menu_list').addClass('hidden');
 });
});
```

After correcting the semantics and applying css fixes, the final solution would be like the following

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qQ22G/2/)

*Side note: note that the answers using `event.stopPropagation()` method won't work with dynamically created elements. Since it prevents event delegation*

Comment: Thanks for pointing out semantically error .What about this          <a><li><img /><p></p><img/></li></a> what bout this .

Comment: That also is incorrect, list items should be inside a list.. :) why use an `<li>` here..? you can use a `<div>` instead right..?

Comment: Since "a" is inline-element , so styling "a" tag is difficult so i used "li" . Yeah i can use "Div" .

Answer (score 0):

Try this script if you want to be able to close the list by clicking outside the menu_list.

```
  <script>
    $(document).click(function(e){
       if ($(e.target).attr('id') == 'menu')
          $('#menu_list').toggle();
       else
          $('#menu_list').hide();  
    });

    $('#menu_list').click(function(){
        $('#menu_list').hide();
    });
    </script>
```

Try it out in jsfiddle, I made an example for you how it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/LsZ53/52/